# How do i get list of all the files including their path using java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the list of all the files with their path. My code below does not meet my requirement. It just gives me the file name of the directory.

For Example : below is my input 
\dir\temp1.txt
\dir\dir1\temp2.txt

I want to create a file may be temp.json and dump the file names with their path in it.

```
const fs   = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Dir');
console.log(directoryPath);

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files){

    if (err) {
        return console.log("Unable to scan directory" + err);
    }
    files.forEach(function (file){
        console.log(file);
    })

});
```

is there anyone who can guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this implementation:

```
const walkSync = (dir, filelist = []) => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  for (const file of files) {
    const dirFile = path.join(dir, file);
    const dirent = fs.statSync(dirFile);
    if (dirent.isDirectory()) {
      console.log('directory', path.join(dir, file));
      var odir = {
        file: dirFile,
        files: []
      }
      odir.files = walkSync(dirFile, dir.files);
      filelist.push(odir);
    } else {
      filelist.push({
        file: dirFile
      });
    }
  }
  return filelist;
};
```

Look into this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kethinov/6658166)

Comment: How about an explanation!